# Is there a way to have multiple winners?

Tags: endless-space, endless-space-disharmony

Question is pretty much in the title: is it possible for an alliance to win as one, instead of a single player being the winner?

And if there is such way, is there a difference between classic and disharmony?

Comment: Tritely, I'd suggest that if two factions became allies with everyone but each other and then befriended each  other, that should resolve as a tie. I'm still playing my first MP game, though, so I really don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can change with patches (and mods), but as you can see here http://endlessspace.wikia.com/wiki/Victory , various of the victory conditions imply that you cannot by default have an allied victory, because:

- militarily, you don't win when you annihilate everyone. You win when you conquer 75% of the galaxy (although you could just sum the controlled area of all allies, but then 75% would be an imbalanced value)
- scientifically, you win by being the first to reach a certain tech, and despite being able to trade tech, only one can be the first to reach the victory tech.

And so on.

When such a thing is possible, when you create a game you would fiddle around the options until you find something like "Enable Allied Victory", like in most other games.

Although in some games, this can be selected already inside the game.

Comment: So basically every winning condition is _"be the first player to…"_. I hoped that it would be possible to achieve a diplomatic goal simultaneously, but even then the game will update the score sequentially and the first player who gets updated will win.